# The "Could not find row $id" error

Tags: zend-framework2

A simple question about the getting started (Album) tutorial.
Its' about the deleteAction :

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        if(!$id){
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
        }

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
             $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');

            if($del == 'Yes'){
                 $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');
                 $this->getAlbumTable()->deleteAlbum($id);
            }

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
        }

        return array(
             'id'    => $id,
             'album' => $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id)
        );

    }
```

From what I understand, when an album is deleted from the database, a redirection occurs just after that, to the /album/ route. If I comment (suppress) that redirection, an error "could not find row $id" occurs because getAlbum($id) then tries to retrieve the album that was just deleted, and thus no longer exists...

My question is : is there a way (like a conditional statement on the return array() or getAlbum()) to make things work without the redirection (which should aim at a success page btw)?

Thanks !

Comment: Pretty sure the humble if statement, flash message and a redirect will get you through your woes

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the code. Don't blindly copy paste, understand what's happening there. What you're asking for makes literally no sense.

Once an album is deleted you should see an overview page or a "deleted success" page. This is completely for you to decide what you want to choose but in all cases the redirection is the way to go. There's still the `forward()` plugin, but all it does is to do the redirect internally. There's not really any advantage in doing this for the given use-case that you present.

If you want to return something else than a redirect, then by all means go ahead and return another `ViewModel` that points to a different template.

**TL/DR**: understand the code before you want to modify it.